# Why express.Router() does not work?

Tags: node.js, express

I try to test the sample code bird.js (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). Basically, something like below.

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
```

But when I run it.

```
node bird.js
```

I get this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
```

BTW, 'express' is installed.

EXTRA INFO
    "express": "3.2.x",

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (../route/bird.js:5:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

bird.js is the whole thing that I run.

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Post express version, and the full stack trace. Are you sure is in that line the error? Because that code snippet just works. And is that your whole code, or do you have something else, if so, post it.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande, supplied, thanks.

Comment: Why express 3.2.x instead of 4.16.3?

Comment: "npm update" does not work the way I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using an outdated express version. The documentation you're referring to is for express `4.x.x`, and you're using `3.x.x`.

Update your express version to the latest one, and your code will work fine.

```
npm install express@latest
```

Will update your express version to: `4.16.3`

Comment: I see, I tried "npm update" and thought everything is updated.

Comment: @user180574 if you had `"^3.2.x"` NPM won't update to "4.x.x", but to "3.21.2" since that's a major version update, and could be breaking. You will have to update to a major version manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way.

```
router.use('/',timeLog, function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
    next()
})
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: His code is fine, and the error is `cannot read property 'use' of undefined` meaning that `router` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a server instance of express by invoking `const app = express()`. You then would import bird.js into app.js and run `node app.js`.

See image below:
[image]